# Token contract replacement

Tags: crowdsale

There is a token which already has holders and a smart contract which now should be updated. No other possibilities to replace a contract like proxy has been added, so I need to deploy a new version. Please advice is there any chance to link a new contract to the old token and not to loose token holder and keep token name, symbol etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already a smart contract with some token holders, but the nature of smart contract cannot be updated once you deploy it.

Now one thing you can do is that, deploy a new smart contract with the required updated features.

**1.** Import the addresses of all existing token holders and the amount they had at the vary time of instance.

**2.** Airdrop the new tokens to the addresses with the specific previous amount.

> Once a contract is in the blockchain, it is final and cannot be
>   changed. Certain parameters, of course, can be changed if they are
>   allowed to change via the original code.
>
> One method of updating contracts is to use a versioning system. For
>   example, you could have an entryway contract that just forwards all
>   calls to the most recent version of the contract, as defined by an
>   updatable address parameter. You could also use a name registry, and
>   update that to point to the most recent contract version.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much for this information